# Array of strings gets entirely rewrote when I try to append - C (xv6)

Tags: c, linux, shell, xv6

I am declaring an array of strings by using:

`char *commands[100];`

I then proceed to enter a while loop  that reads commands input from the user:

```
    while(getcmd(buf, sizeof(buf), cmd_count) >= 0){

            printf(2, "cmd_count: %d\n", cmd_count);
            buf[strlen(buf)-1] = 0;
            printf(2, "string buf: -%s-\n", buf);
            commands[cmd_count] = buf;
            printf(2, "commands: %s\n", commands[0]);
            printf(2, "commands: %s\n", commands[1]);
            printf(2, "commands: %s\n", commands[2]);
            printf(2, "commands: %s\n", commands[3]);
            cmd_count++;
    }
```

Here is the output from two iterations:

```
0 EZ$ ls
cmd_count: 0
string buf: -ls-
commands: ls
commands: (null)
commands: (null)
commands: (null)

EZ$ echo hello
cmd_count: 1
string buf: -echo hello-
commands: echo hello
commands: echo hello
commands: (null)
commands: (null)
```

Even though `cmd_count` was clearly 1 on the second iteration, it rewrote both the 0th and 1st position. What gives?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: `printf(2, "cmd_count: %d\n", cmd_count);` should be `printf("cmd_count: %d\n", cmd_count);` Your attempt yields `"warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you're probably not testing in an xv6 environment

Comment: Ah, you are probably right. Thanks Tom. Now I know it is one of those quirky things like CS50...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing your entire algorithm, a simple approach may be:

- currently you have the variable command allocated to hold 100 char pointers, so that gives you room to handle cmd_count 0 - 99.
- but you only have a single buffer for storing each command
- if you do need to store each command past the while loop in which you read them, how about the following approach:

allocate a buffer for each pointer in commands that is big enough to hold a command

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    commands[i] = malloc(MAXSTRINGSIZE + 1);
}
```

(you could probably optimize this by allocating ((MAXSTRINGSIZE + 1) * 100) and then setting each pointer in commands to the correct offset, but the approach above may be easier for you to understand if you are just learning about pointers)

- And then try replacing buf in the getcmd() call with commands[i], so that you read the command directly into an entry in the commands array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that getcmd() does not allocate space for the buffer 'buf', that you  allocate that space outside of getcmd()?  If so, then the following line:

```
commands[cmd_count] = buf;
```

Does not allocate a new buffer, it simply updates one of your char pointers to point to your one buffer.  So after two iterations, both commands[0] and commands[1] point to the same buffer, 'buf'.

Comment: You would be correct.. how would you suggest I fix this? Is there a different data structure I could use for creating an array of strings rather than using char pointers?